# Apache Camel difference between Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED and Exchange.FAILURE_HANDLED property

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel Framework and going through the documentation regarding the error handling , i am confused between `Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED` and `Exchange.FAILURE_HANDLED` properties

`Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED`: As per my understanding this property is to propagate the exception back to caller.

but not able to find any information `Exchange.FAILURE_HANDLED` on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are internal flags and should not be in-use by end users.

Comment: @Clause Isben, I understand that these flag should not be used by end users, but just for the knowledge i was looking for the difference between the two..as it sometimes helps us to debug the legacy code where custom error handling has been done. for example when use splitter eip with aggregator sometimes we need to remove the error handling related properties from exchange